# Nodejs "net" - How to send messages from server in Unicode instead of ASCII?

Tags: node.js, unicode, serverside-javascript

I am making a chat application and I can manage to send messages in Unicode from the clients, but if I write an instruction in the server code (nodejs script with net framework), for example attaching the nick of the sender to the message, it makes the message garbled.

Example:
                sockets[i].write(socket.id + ": " + msg_sent);

If msg_sent is in ASCII (encoded as ascii in the client), it works fine, but if I encode it as Unicode, the instruction makes the message unreadable.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The default encoding for strings passed to `socket.write()` is UTF-8. What is your client written in?

Comment: c# clients
ok, it is utf8, but how to make it be in utf16?

Answer (score 0):

If you need UTF-16, node supports the 'utf16le' encoding which is UTF-16 in little-endian format. To use that, simply specify the encoding:

```
sockets[i].write(socket.id + ": " + msg_sent, 'utf16le');
```

If you need some other encoding that node does not natively support, you will need to use something like [iconv](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv).

Comment: IS 'utf16be' supported?
Is there any documentation about this topic? Thanks.

Comment: 'utf16be' is not supported in node core. You may have to use something like [iconv](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv) if you need anything beyond the [built-in encodings](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer).